# Multiple infowindows open, toggle with checkbox, infowindow.close problem

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am creating a map where clicking the marker or a checkbox opens or closes the markers infowindow. Multiple infowindows will be visible simultaneously.
My code so far works, except closing the infowindow from the checkbox closes the last opened infowindow, rather than the one that corresponds to that checkbox's marker.

I suspect I am not using infowindow.close properly, I've tried

```
infowindow.close(marker);  
infowindow.close(markers[i]);  
infowindow.close(this); 
infowindow.close(map,markers[i]);
```

**HTML**

```
<fieldset id="form">
    <p>
    <input class="checkbox" id="Dial-a-Ride" name="Dial-a-Ride" type="checkbox" value="Dial-a-Ride" />
    <label for="Dial-a-Ride">Dial-a-Ride</label>
    </p>
    <p>
    <input class="checkbox" id="American Legion" name="American Legion" type="checkbox" value="American Legion" />
    <label for="American Legion">American Legion</label>
    </p>
    <p>
    <input class="checkbox" id="Veterans of Foreign Wars" name="Veterans of Foreign Wars" type="checkbox" value="Veterans of Foreign Wars" />
    <label for="Veterans of Foreign Wars">Veterans of Foreign Wars</label>
    </p>
    <p>
    <input class="checkbox" id="Nutrition" name="Nutrition" type="checkbox" value="Nutrition" />
    <label for="Nutrition">Nutrition</label>
    </p>
</fieldset>
  <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>

<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**JS**

```
$(window).load(function(){

   var markers = [];
    var iconSrc = {};

var locations = [
['Boonton Town', '973-402-9410, ext. 631', 'Dial-a-Ride', 40.902, -74.407, 1],
['Whippanong Post', '12-32 Legion Pl.<br>Whippany, NJ 07981', 'American Legion',40.824445559459136, -74.42361831665039,52 ],
['Rockaway Post #9328', '23 Pawnee Ave.<br>Rockaway, NJ 07886', 'Veterans of Foreign Wars', 40.920517319192335, -74.51099395751953,64],
['Roxbury Township', 'Roxbury Senior Center, 72 Eyland Avenue<br>(973) 361-5231; open Wednesday and Friday', 'Nutrition', 40.8563177, -74.637607,79 ]
];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {

      zoom: 10,

      center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.7967667, -74.4815438),

      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

    });

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  

      marker = new google.maps.Marker({

        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][3], locations[i][4]),

        map: map,

        icon: iconSrc[locations[i][2]]
      });

      markers.push(marker);

     var infowindow;   

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {

        return function() {
            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                    infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]+"<br />"+locations[i][2]+"<br />"+locations[i][1]);

        infowindow.open(map,marker);

        }
      })(marker, i));
    }


      function show(category) {

        for (var i=0; i<locations.length; i++) {

          if (locations[i][2] == category) {
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]+"<br />"+locations[i][2]+"<br />"+locations[i][1]);

          infowindow.open(map, markers[i]);

          }
        }
      }


      function hide(category) {

        for (var i=0; i<locations.length; i++) {

          if (locations[i][2] == category) {
 infowindow.close(marker);
          }
        }
      }      
        $(".checkbox").click(function(){

            var cat = $(this).attr("value");        

            // If checked

            if ($(this).is(":checked"))

            {
                show(cat);
            }
            else
            {
                hide(cat);
            }
          });
});
```

If you click checkbox 1, then checkbox 2, the corresponding infowindows open, uncheck box 1, infowindow 2 closes, as it was the last opened, this is wrong, infowindow 1 should have closed.

jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Verdomde/bdpw89sv/104/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have a reference to a single infowindow.  To have multiple infowindows open at a time, and close them, you need to keep references to all of the infowindows.  The simplest way to do that is to attach them to their associated marker.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
  return function() {
    if (!this.infowindow)
      this.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    this.infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0] + "<br />" + locations[i][2] + "<br />" + locations[i][1]);

    this.infowindow.open(map, marker);
  }
  })(marker, i));
}
```

Then in your show and hide functions open or close those.  Note that the [InfoWindow.close()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/info-window#InfoWindow.close) function doesn't have any arguments.

```
// == shows all markers of a particular category, and ensures the checkbox is checked ==
function show(category) {
  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    if (locations[i][2] == category) {
      if (!markers[i].infowindow)
        markers[i].infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
      markers[i].infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0] + "<br />" + locations[i][2] + "<br />" + locations[i][1]);
      markers[i].infowindow.open(map, markers[i]);
    }
  }
}

// == hides all markers of a particular category, and ensures the checkbox is cleared ==
function hide(category) {
  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    if (locations[i][2] == category) {
      markers[i].infowindow.close();
    }
  }
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/y8ajLuz1/3/)

**code snippet:**

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  var markers = [];
  var iconSrc = {};
  var locations = [
    ['Boonton Town', '973-402-9410, ext. 631', 'Dial-a-Ride', 40.902, -74.407, 1],
    ['Whippanong Post', '12-32 Legion Pl.<br>Whippany, NJ 07981', 'American Legion', 40.824445559459136, -74.42361831665039, 52],
    ['Rockaway Post #9328', '23 Pawnee Ave.<br>Rockaway, NJ 07886', 'Veterans of Foreign Wars', 40.920517319192335, -74.51099395751953, 64],
    ['Roxbury Township', 'Roxbury Senior Center, 72 Eyland Avenue<br>(973) 361-5231; open Wednesday and Friday', 'Nutrition', 40.8563177, -74.637607, 79],
    ["Dover American Legion", " 2 Legion Pl, Dover, NJ", 'American Legion', 40.882275, -74.56038999999998, 72]
  ];

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.7967667, -74.4815438),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var marker, i;

  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][3], locations[i][4]),
      map: map
    });
    markers.push(marker);


    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
        if (!this.infowindow)
          this.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        this.infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0] + "<br />" + locations[i][2] + "<br />" + locations[i][1]);

        this.infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    })(marker, i));
  }
  // == shows all markers of a particular category, and ensures the checkbox is checked ==
  function show(category) {
    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
      if (locations[i][2] == category) {
        if (!markers[i].infowindow)
          markers[i].infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        markers[i].infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0] + "<br />" + locations[i][2] + "<br />" + locations[i][1]);
        markers[i].infowindow.open(map, markers[i]);
      }
    }
  }

  // == hides all markers of a particular category, and ensures the checkbox is cleared ==
  function hide(category) {
    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
      if (locations[i][2] == category) {
        markers[i].infowindow.close(marker);
      }
    }
  }

  $(".checkbox").click(function() {
    var cat = $(this).attr("value");
    // If checked
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      show(cat);
    } else {
      hide(cat);
    }
  });
}); //]]>
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#map {
  height: 60%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset id="form">
  <p>
    <input class="checkbox" id="Dial-a-Ride" name="Dial-a-Ride" type="checkbox" value="Dial-a-Ride" />
    <label for="Dial-a-Ride">Dial-a-Ride</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input class="checkbox" id="American Legion" name="American Legion" type="checkbox" value="American Legion" />
    <label for="American Legion">American Legion</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input class="checkbox" id="Veterans of Foreign Wars" name="Veterans of Foreign Wars" type="checkbox" value="Veterans of Foreign Wars" />
    <label for="Veterans of Foreign Wars">Veterans of Foreign Wars</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input class="checkbox" id="Nutrition" name="Nutrition" type="checkbox" value="Nutrition" />
    <label for="Nutrition">Nutrition</label>
  </p>
</fieldset>
<div id="map" "></div>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk" type="text/javascript "></script>
```

Comment: Absolutely, awesome.
This works as I was hoping, very clearly described as well. I appreciate your time.